# How to set ObjectId as a data type in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Using node.js, mongodb on mongoHQ and mongoose. I'm setting a schema for Categories. I would like to use the document ObjectId as my categoryId.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var Schema_Category = new Schema({
    categoryId  : ObjectId,
    title       : String,
    sortIndex   : String
});
```

I then run

```
var Category = mongoose.model('Schema_Category');
var category = new Category();
category.title = "Bicycles";
category.sortIndex = "3";

category.save(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log('saved');
  mongoose.disconnect();     
});
```

Notice that I don't provide a value for categoryId. I assumed mongoose will use the schema to generate it but the document has the usual "_id" and not "categoryId". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Unlike traditional RBDMs, mongoDB doesn't allow you to define any random field as the primary key, the _id field MUST exist for all standard documents.

For this reason, it doesn't make sense to create a separate uuid field.

In mongoose, the ObjectId type is used not to create a new uuid, rather it is mostly used to reference other documents.

Here is an example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var Schema_Product = new Schema({
    categoryId  : ObjectId, // a product references a category _id with type ObjectId
    title       : String,
    price       : Number
});
```

As you can see, it wouldn't make much sense to populate categoryId with a ObjectId.

However, if you do want a nicely named uuid field, mongoose provides virtual properties that allow you to proxy (reference) a field.

Check it out:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var Schema_Category = new Schema({
    title       : String,
    sortIndex   : String
});

Schema_Category.virtual('categoryId').get(function() {
    return this._id;
});
```

So now, whenever you call category.categoryId, mongoose just returns the _id instead.

You can also create a "set" method so that you can set virtual properties, check out [this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html)
for more info

Comment: After setting a virtual property, I tried:
db.cats.find({categoryId: ObjectId("the id")}) but got null results.
when I use db.cats.find({_id: ObjectId("the id")}) I did get a doc back. So it looks like the virtual property cannot be used for searching.
I think it could be easier to manage the code if it was possible to reference each ID using a clear name, rather than using _id for everything. Just a thought...

Comment: `ObjectId` should be referenced with `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Answer (score 58):

I was looking for a different answer for the question title, so maybe other people will be too.

To set type as an ObjectId (so you may reference `author` as the author of `book`, for example), you may do like:

```
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', {
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // here you set the author ID
                                          // from the Author colection, 
                                          // so you can reference it
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution on using ObjectId

```
// usermodel.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId


let UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {
     type: String
   },
   events: [{
     type: ObjectId,
     ref: 'Event' // Reference to some EventSchema
   }]
})

UserSchema.set('autoIndex', true)

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Using mongoose's [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method

```
// controller.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./usermodel.js')

let query = User.findOne({ name: "Person" })

query.exec((err, user) => {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err)
  }

  user.events = events
  // user.events is now an array of events
})
```

Comment: how would you add default value in the events field ?.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by @dex worked for me. But I want to add something else that also worked for me: Use

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {
     type: String
   },
   events: [{
     type: ObjectId,
     ref: 'Event' // Reference to some EventSchema
   }]
})
```

if what you want to create is an Array reference. But if what you want is an Object reference, which is what I think you might be looking for anyway, remove the brackets from the *value* prop, like this:

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: {
     type: String
   },
   events: {
     type: ObjectId,
     ref: 'Event' // Reference to some EventSchema
   }
})
```

Look at the 2 snippets well. In the second case, the value prop of key events does not have brackets over the object def.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly define the ObjectId

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
categoryId  : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
title       : String,
sortIndex   : String
})

Note: You need to import the mongoose module

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to transform your _id to something you like.

Here's an example with a Page-Document that I implemented for a project:

```
interface PageAttrs {
    label: string
    // ...
}

const pageSchema = new mongoose.Schema<PageDoc>(
    {
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
        // ...
    },
    {
        toJSON: {
            transform(doc, ret) {
                // modify ret directly
                ret.id = ret._id
                delete ret._id
            }
        }
    }
)

pageSchema.statics.build = (attrs: PageAttrs) => {
    return new Page({
        label: attrs.label,
        // ...
    })
}

const Page = mongoose.model<PageDoc, PageModel>('Page', pageSchema)
```

Now you can directly access the property 'id', e.g. in a unit test like so:

```
it('implements optimistic concurrency', async () => {
    const page = Page.build({
        label: 'Root Page'
        // ...
    })

    await page.save()

    const firstInstance = await Page.findById(page.id)
    const secondInstance = await Page.findById(page.id)

    firstInstance!.set({ label: 'Main Page' })
    secondInstance!.set({ label: 'Home Page' })

    await firstInstance!.save()

    try {
        await secondInstance!.save()
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err)
        return
    }

    throw new Error('Should not reach this point')
})
```