# Correct way to search for MongoDB entries by '_id' in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using `MongoDb` (as part of `MongoJS`) in `Node`. [Here is the documentation for MongoJS](https://github.com/gett/mongojs).

I'm trying to do a call within Node based on an entry's `_id` field. When using vanilla `MongoDB` from the console, I can do:

`db.products.find({"_id":ObjectId("51d151c6b918a71d170000c7")})`

and it correctly returns my entry. However, when I do the same thing in Node, like:

```
db.products.find({"_id": ObjectId("51d151c6b918a71d170000c7")}, function (err, record) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

I get `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`.

What is the correct protocol for doing this?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You need to require the ObjectId function before using it:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Comment: I used `var ObjectId = require("mongojs").ObjectId;`, but works just as well! Cheers.

Comment: Or [`require('mongoose').Schema.ObjectId`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111846/how-to-set-objectid-as-a-data-type-in-mongoose)

Comment: The Mongoose schema one didn't work for me. Mongodb did.

Comment: As per `Mongoose`,

_To create a new ObjectId please try `Mongoose.Types.ObjectId` instead of using `Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`. Set the `suppressWarning` option if you're trying to create a hex char path in your schema._

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MongoJS, you can do:

```
var ObjectId = mongojs.ObjectId;
```

Then,

```
db.users.find({"_id": ObjectId(id)}, function(err, user){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using mongoose you can try this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
usersSchema = mongoose.model('users'),
mongoose.Types.ObjectId("<object_id>")

usersSchema.find({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("<object_id>")}, function (err, record) {
// Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also destructure your ObjectId and MongoClient to optimize your code and make it more readable.

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to utilise objectId when using mongoose.

```
// at the top of the file
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = Mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

// when using mongo to collect data
Mongoose.model('users', userSchema).findOne({ _id: 
    ObjectId('xyz') }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user)
        return handle(req, res)
    })
})
```