# StandardJs + ES6 extended class - Useless constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, extends

This is my model class:

```
'use strict'

import MongoDb from 'database/mongodb'

export default class Model {
  constructor (options) {
    this.data = this.sanitize(options)
  }

  objectId (_id) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545311/correct-way-to-search-for-mongodb-entries-by-id-in-node
    const mongodb = new MongoDb()
    const objectId = mongodb.objectId
    return objectId(_id)
  }

  async db () {
    const mongodb = new MongoDb()
    const connection = await mongodb.connect()
    return connection
  }

  sanitize (options) {
    return options
  }

  async insert (options) {
    //
  }

  async find (options) {
    //
  }

  async remove (options) {
    //
  }
}
```

And I have a user class extends from it:

```
'use strict'

import lodash from 'lodash'
import Model from 'model'
import schemas from './schemas'

export default class User extends Model {
  constructor (options) {
    super(options)
  }

  sanitize (options) {
    let data = options || {}
    let schema = schemas.user
    let keys = lodash.keys(schema)
    let defaults = lodash.defaults(data, schema)
    let picked = lodash.pick(defaults, keys)    
    return picked
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

But according to [standardjs](https://standardjs.com/):

```
standard: Use JavaScript Standard Style (https://standardjs.com)
  /var/www/html/.../user/models/user.js:8:3: Useless constructor.
```

Why my `constructor` is `Useless`?

From what I understand, I **must** use `super()` in my extended class even though I don't quite fully understand it yet. Did I use it wrong?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

If I **omit** the `constructor` in the extended class, I will get this error:

```
Syntax Error: missing super() call in constructor
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  constructor (...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
```

will be default constructor in extended class when `constructor` is omitted. That's why it was marked as 'useless'.

`super` should be specified in extended class only when there is `constructor`, and `constructor` should be specified only when there should be some logic besides calling parent constructor with exact same arguments.

Comment: and [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4925) is a comment from [eslint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint) confirming the same!

Comment: To think about it another way, when extending a class you wouldn't call each method just to call super inside of it.  So why would you do it with the constructor?  It is just a special method.

Comment: @DanielGimenez I wouldn't extrapolate it like that because constructor is really special, it's more than `constructor` property on prototype object, it isn't prototypically inherited from parent as other methods. But the direction of thought is correct, the classes are syntactic sugar for constructor functions that was designed to not require unnecessary input.