# Schema.ObjectId not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im not sure why Schema.ObjectId is not working on my model, I have the latest version of mongoose.

this is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    team_name : {
        type: String,
        index : true
    },
    dateCreated : {
        type : Date
    },
    memberId : {
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }
});

var Team = module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);


module.exports.createTeam = function(newTeam, callback){

    newTeam.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

I also tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111846/how-to-set-objectid-as-a-data-type-in-mongoose) still not working. can anyone help on this? thanks

this is the json file of my data, and its weird the memberId is not showing

```
[
  {
    "_id": "587da4a9141f1619f42ac66d",
    "dateCreated": "2017-01-17T04:59:21.000Z",
    "team_name": "Sample Team",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you're saving an Object Id to the DB? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13851334/1893672 Test it before saving to be sure it's an objectId.

Comment: I want to declare memberId as Schema.ObjectId, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with your schema.

Mongoose defines a new `ObjectId` only for `_id` field. For all other fields of type `ObjectId` you have to pass a new `ObjectId` value to it.

So if the field `memberId` is for holding an `ObjectId` that refers to a member in another collection (eg. members), you can pass the `_id` value of a member of members collection into `memberId`. (Also adding a `ref` in your schema to that collection would be helpful)

If memberId is a totally new `ObjectId` and not related to any other collection, then you can generate a new unique `ObjectId` with the function **`mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`** and save it to memberId field.

So do this before saving newMember:

```
newMember.memberId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

Hope that helps!