# Is it safe to create multiple ObjectID fields within single mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've looked [in official manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) for explanations on "what is `ObjectId` type is"

They state that if a document lacks object id then it will be created:

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id
>   field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the
>   _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field.

Wording was too implicit. What if i define my own objectId fields with different name, like `parentID`? Will it use it as document id, or create additional "internal" `_id` field.

I want to create tree-like structure in database, where each object - a document - **must** have its own id, plus it **may** have a parent, and an array of siblings (which could be either empty, or filled with some `objectId`s).

I require tree-like navigation for mongoose in express app, so i thought `Schema.findById()` methods are the best way to go - they provide object lookup, as well as type cast checking, and ensures `objectId` is also being unique per document (not required custom-written hashing function)

So Is it safe to use multiple `objectId`s in a single document in such a way?

---

Here is [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111846/how-to-set-objectid-as-a-data-type-in-mongoose), it showed that I may use `Schema.ObjectId`.

Comment: yes it's safe. take a look at the mongoose docs. Its recommended. when you declare the type , use Schema.Type.ObjectId

Comment: @THEWOLF thanks, i tried, that workes. Array of [ObjectID] is also supported, i was able to do `$push`es into it