# How to define an objectId type in mongoose 6.0.0^

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am seeing many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41596974/9953550) saying that the correct way to define an objectId type in a mongoose schema is like:

```
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

But from the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) they show that you can define an objectId type like so:

```
const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ driver: mongoose.ObjectId });
```

Is there something I am missing? What is the correct way to define an objectId type? Are both methods correct or one is outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these roads lead to Rome, there is no single "correct" way.

The type is defined in https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema/index.js#L24 as

```
exports.ObjectId = require('./objectid');
```

The rest are the pointers to this export. Some are shorter, some are longer unless you use them in the context.

The `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`  comes from there: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js

```
Schema.Types = MongooseTypes = require('./schema/index');
```

`mongoose.ObjectId`  comes from https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/index.js#L940

```
Mongoose.prototype.ObjectId = SchemaTypes.ObjectId;
```